# Executing code immediately after navigation: Browser plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, same-origin-policy

I am building a tool which uses (dynamically inserted) JavaScript to modify webpages. Any webpage.

The idea is to allow a user to use it to record a series of changes to an existing webpage like `google.com`, (for the sake of example suppose a change is to apply a 10 pixel solid black border to all `<img>` tags, this change can obviously be encoded as a short and sweet snippet of jQuery), and the tool generates a link (or identifier) that contains this metadata and the url representing the "starting point" if you will (in this case `google.com`).

Now the problem I've run into is the entire Same-Origin security policy, whose purpose is to expressly deny the exact kind of thing that it seems like I need to do.

What I need to do is essentially navigate to a particular site, and then execute javascript in the context of that site. Neither I (the author of the tool) nor the user with whom I share my script necessarily have control over the site, so in theory the security model if implemented properly should prevent this concept from working.

Because of this I cannot have a single clickable link that kicks off the process of running my code on some site. It totally makes sense too. It would make it trivial for an attacker site to send a disguised clickable link that will run code that acts as me on any site they want.

But, the way to get around it is to tell the recipient to do a **single additional step**. First they open the URL of the site just like normal, then they paste a bit of `javascript:(function(){.....})();` into the URL/omni bar. That is (AFAICT) completely legitimate and should be permissible because the user understands that this script is being executed. Whether or not it should be allowed to run JS so easily at this point is more or less irrelevant, as it basically just works everywhere now.

This isn't too bad but I think the user experience suffers unnecessarily. For example it looks like a native app would be necessary to get any better than pasting the JS into the URL bar on an iOS device for example, but on a plugin-accepting full browser it seems like a plugin can achieve what I want.

Which is: a navigation to an arbitrary URL followed by code execution (this code originating from an authorized source) with one click.

But I'm not sure where to start. What API could provide me this ability? I am hoping I can get away with Greasemonkey-type scripting (as Greasemonkey compatible plugins are available for pretty much all the good browsers), but I can't tell if there is enough power available.

I am actually still a little unsure about security related problems with this. I used to have a huge paragraph here but it all boils down to "social engineering".

Answer (score 0):

This kind of things are generally done with [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

On your website featuring your script, create a link that has `href="javascript:(function(){/* ... */})()"`. Then a user could simply drag and drop that link into his favourites (bookmark it). And use it as button in a favourites bar.

Your bookmarklet could contain directly your script, or a simple loader that injects a `<script src=http://mywebsite.com/script.js">` tag into the document, this way you can update your script and "distribute" it directly to all users.

Comment: Oh I like that! Updating the script on the server-side. Good insight there.

Answer (score 0):

Security is always about knowledge. Or to put it the other way around: Not knowing something makes you feel insecure.

There is no secure way to do what you want which is my web browsers forbid it by default. There are workarounds (like pasting the URL as you explained above) but all of them are only secure as long as the user knows what she is doing.

That being the social implications. Now the technical solutions:

1. You try a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)
2. You can use a browser plugin like [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)

Both allow to run arbitrary JavaScript. The former needs explicit permission from the user each time, the later one does it automatically.

Of course, if you move the core of the functionality to a remote place, it would be hard for even knowledgeable users like me to understand and trust what is going on.

That is when the meat of the function isn't in the bookmarklet or the greasemonkey script and when you instead add a `<script>` tag with a remote URL. That would make it harder to make sure your script doesn't do something "odd". For example, you could return a different script when I try to download the JavaScript without using your bookmarklet.

Comment: Can Greasemonkey auto-execute non-predetermined code? does it allow for such a thing? User A needs to send to User B (who has Greasemonkey) multiple different scripts/configuration links and I want user B to be able to execute them without individually installing them (as would be necessary with bookmarklets or pasting script into URL bar).

Comment: Can you do an AJAX request in greasemonkey and call `eval()` on the success result?

Comment: Then I missed an important requirement or you didn't tell me about it. My approach would be: Upload the scripts on a server, send GM script to B which downloads and executes the scripts from step #1.